# ClaimType to store avatar URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

I use Facebook/Google authentication in my application and once authenticated I create my own cookie.

What `ClaimType` is appropriate for storing user's avatar URI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not required to stick with the `ClaimTypes` enumeration if you can't find a match as strings are supported.

It's perfectly valid to use a string:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Gravatar", user.GravatarLink));
```

to get the claim back out:

```
var gravatar = HttpContext.User.Claims
                  .Where(c => c.Type == "Gravatar")
                  .Select(c => c.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

The obvious downside of this is that this is a 'magical' string that can potentially be mistyped and break at runtime. If you absolutely want strong typing for these extra types create your own static type that provides the custom claims:

```
public static class MyClaimTypes 
{
    public static string Gravatar = "Gravatar";
    public static string FullName = "FullName";
}
```

which ensures you get strong typing instead of magic strings. Now you can replace the `"Gravatar"` string with `MyClaimTypes.Gravatar` in your code.